# Combine strings, extract substrings

Tags: python, string

(I'm using python)

I'm working with a large file of RNA sequences, and I'm trying to reformat it to use in a clustering program. My file is made up of two types of 'lines.' 1) Accession numbers for bacteria, (period) the nucleotide this sequence starts at, (period) the nucleotide it ends at. 2) lines of the actual sequence itself (across multiple lines, even though it's a continuous sequence):

> >A45315.1.1521\n
>   GACGAACGCUGGCGGCGUGCCUAAUACAUGCAAGUCGAGCGCAGGAAGCCGGCGGAUCCC\n
>   UUCGGGGUGAANCCGGUGGAAUGAGCGGCGGACGGGUGAGUAACACGUGGGCAACCUACC\n
>   UUGUAGACUGGGAUAACUCCGGGAAACCGGGGCUAAUACCGGAUGAUCAUUUGGAUCGCAU\n
>   GAUCCGAAUGUAAAAGUGGGGAUUUAUCCUCACACUGCAAGAUGGGCCCGCGGCGCA…..
>   >A93610.15.1301\n
>   CCACUGCUAUGGGGGUCCGACUAAGCCAUGCGAGUCAUGGGGUCCCUCUGGGACACCACC\n
>   GGCGGACGGCUCAGUAACACGUCGGUAACCUACCCUCGGGAGGGGGAUAACCCCGGGAAA\n
>   CUGGGGCUAAUCCCCCAUAGGCCUGAGGUACUGGAAGGUCCUCAGGCCGAAAGGGGCUU….

I need to create something that looks at the lines that start with >, and go to the number after the first decimal (so above that would be 1 and 15). Starting a count at that number (so 1 or 15 in the above example), it needs to extract the nucleotides (As,Cs,Gs or Us) that start at 69 and go to 497 (note for this example I took out a bunch of the nucleotides).

So, for my attempt, I thought it would make sense to make the nucleotide sequences into one long string, and then try to extract the nucleotides. But I can't seem to make the lines of RNA sequences into one long string (see below for what I tried). And once I have the large string, I'm not sure how to extract the right nucleotides. I need to write something like s = [x:497], where x is 69-(insert that number before the first decimal).

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
 #Make a program that takes SSURef_NR99 file of sequences, makes a new file of 
 #Accession numbers and size of 16S.
 import re
 infilename = 'SSUtestdata.txt'
 outfilename = 'SSUtestdata3.txt'

 #Here I'm trying to search for one of the nucleotides, an end of line character and     another nucleotide, trying to make a long string.

 replace = re.compile(r'([A|C|G|U])(\n)([A|C|G|U])')

 #remove extra letters and spaces
 with open(infilename, 'r') as infile, open(outfilename, 'w') as outfile:
     for line in infile:
          line = replace.sub(r'\1\3', line)

 #Write to OutFile
          outfile.write(line)
```

Thank you for any ideas you might have!

Comment: is it always 69-497? Then what is the significance of 1 and 15?

Comment: For each bacteria, the gene is about 1600 nucleotides long. So 1 means that the sequence above starts at 1 (of 1600) and 15 means that the sequence starts at 15 (of 1600). I always need to extract nucleotides 69-497 (from the 1600)

Comment: So the first one, A45315.1.1521, means that the following nucleotides span nucleotides 1 to 1521. The second one, A93610.15.1301, means that the following nucleotides span 15 to 1521. I want nucleotides 69-497 (see where I run into trouble, with the starting point being different? I can't just start a count at 1, since they don't always start at one)

Comment: For the second one, did you mean `15 to 1301`?

Comment: Are the files too big to read into memory?  If so, then you need to be a little clever about how you know where to start reading each sequence.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget oops yes! :p

Comment: @cm2 yes, that's exactly the problem, or else I would have used text wrangler (or something) to just quickly make one big string!

Comment: I just don't understand why this `line = replace.sub(r'\1\3', line)` doesn't get right of the end-of-line characters...

Comment: Is this the standard Fasta format? Is something like biopython not an option?

Comment: I don't think that regex works because each `line` in `infile` is separated by an EOL character.  So your compiled regex won't catch anything on that line.

Comment: @cm2 I was wondering if it was that… I tried removing all the EOL, and then reinserting EOL at the correct spots but that did not work (started inserting at weird places)

Comment: @benjamin it was fasta, but I've made it a text file so I can use regular python (I've never used biopython before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this, although not as elegant as @inspectorG4dget's solution.

```
with open(infilename) as infile:
    nucStart=69
    nucStop=497
    nucleotides=[]
    for line in infile:
        if line.startswith(">"): 
            # process the previous list if populated
            if len(nucleotides) > 0:
                nucleotides = ''.join(nucleotides)  # make a single string
                # write out the accession information and the nucleotides we want
                outfile.write("%s %s" % (accession_line,
                                         nucleotides[nucStart-start-1:nucStop-start]))
                nucleotides=[]   # clear it for the next run
            # this is the start of the next sequence
            accession_line = line
            start = int(line.split('.')[1])
        else:
            # this is a line containing a partial nucleotide sequence, so add it
            nucleotides.append(line)
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm trying it but nothing seems to be happening… do you have any suggestions? Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that at the end you will want to print `seq`.  Alternatively, instead of the `seq.append(...)` line, just use `print nucleotides[nucStart-start-1:nucStop-start]`.  That will dump out the 69 to 497 nucleotides for each bacteria.

Comment: That's great, it worked, thank you!! I tried changing the `print nucleotides[nucStart-start-1:nucStop-start]` to `outfile.write(nucleotides[nucStart-start-1:nucStop-start])` so that I could save it, and that works but do you know how I might change this so I could keep the lines that begin with \> (so that the accession numbers associated with these sections are kept?)

Comment: I've edited the answer to reflect your changes via `outfile.write(...)` and to show how to keep the accession information.  Basically, you just save the line to a variable and then dump it to a file along with the nucleotides string.

Comment: BEAUTIFUL! Thank you! I marked this as the accepted answer, and I'm sorry to keep pestering you, but I'm hoping you might help me with one more thing? I changed this line `outfile.write(**"%s %s"** % (access…` to `outfile.write(**"\n%s%s"** % (access…`  because I need the accession lines on their own lines, and no spaces between the %s %s values. BUT, of course this adds an EOL character to the beginning of the file, do you know how I could remove this from my `outfile`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  The first `%s` corresponds to the `accession_line`, and the second `%s` to the `nucleotides`.  If you want it to be like your input where the accession info is on a single line and then the 69--497 nucleotides are on the second line (this time as a single string), then you want to change that to `"%s\n%s"`.

Comment: Actually, it's okay, I just delete the line and it's fine! thanks again for all your help, this works perfectly :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly, this should do it:

```
with open('path/to/input') as infile:
  while 1:
    try:
      line = infile.readline()
      _, start, end = line.strip().split('.')
      start, end = int(start), int(end)
      beg = infile.read(start-1)
      infile.read(beg.count('\n'))
      seq = infile.read(end-start)
      extra = infile.read(seq.count('\n'))
      seq = seq.replace('\n') + extra
      print seq  # print(seq) in python3
    except:
      break
```

Comment: Thanks! This is probably I dumb question but what is the `('path/to/input')`?

Comment: `'path/to/input'` is the path to the input file that you want to read.

Comment: of course, ugh! Thanks for this, but I get 'invalid syntax' for this line `seq = seq.replace('\n') + extra` with an arrow pointing at the 'q' in `seq = `, why do you think that's happening?

Comment: The `extra = ` line needed an additional `)` at the end.  I've submitted an edit to the post.

Comment: Would I replace `int(start), int(end)` with `int(69), int(497)`? I'm just wondering where I specify the numbers to use to extract the sequence I want. Thanks!

Comment: @Jen: That's the part I'm still not fully clear about. The `start` and `end` refer to `1` and `1521` in the first case and `15` and `1301` in the second. If you want to start from the `15+69`th nucleotide in the second case, then you'll need to add the `69` to `start` (and change `end` appropriately`